# ownProps doesn't pass down the value of variable to return

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning my React with Redux. I don't understand why my ownProps variable 'id' doesn't pass down the value in my MapStateToProps function. I was able to console.log the value of 'id', however it does't recognize when I use find() method to see matching the post.id and variable 'id' value. The error message is

> × TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I thought I'm doing everything correct, apparently it not. Hoping anybody can help me out.

**This is in my App.js:**

```
import ApiSingle from './components/api/api_post.component';
<Route path='/:post_id' component={ApiSingle} />
```

**This is in my component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class ApiSingle extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(this.props.post)
        const {post, id} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
               <h1>{post.title}</h1>
               {console.log(post)}
               {console.log(id)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.post_id
    return {
        posts: state.api.posts.find(post => post.id === id),
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ApiSingle)
```

Comment: Is `post.id` a number by chance? Not a string?

Comment: The post.id is a number.

Comment: You probably need to do `const id = parseInt(ownProps.match.params.post_id)`

Comment: id itself has no problem to pass down the value. When I test the id value with console.log(this.props.id), it shows the value of the id correctly, and the value of post value alone test with console.log(this.props.post) and it shows correctly; however when I use find(post=>post.id === id), it doesn't pass down id value.

Comment: The value from the params (`match.params.post_id`) is probably a string since it's coming from the URL. If the id of the object (`post.id`) is a number, the id from the params needs to be parsed into a number first. For example, try this in your console: `123 === '123'`

Comment: Try this before the return in mapStateToProps: `console.log('params.post_id: ', typeof id, ', post.id:', typeof state.api.posts[0].id)`

Comment: You are right! The value of match.params.post_id pass downs as string. Now it works  as I wanted to. I've been working on this for three days... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your prop names are wrong.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.post_id
    return {
        post: state.api.posts.find(post => post.id === id), // post instead of posts
        id, // <== add id
    }
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to return an empty object if there's no matching post, so that "title of undefined" error can be avoided, like this:

```
post: state.api.posts.find(post => post.id === id) || {},
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @technophyle suggested, you'll also want to parse the id from the `match.params` because since it's coming from the URL, it's a string.

```
const id = parseInt(ownProps.match.params.post_id, 10)
```